# jQuery data() leaves actual HTML unchanged

Tags: jquery, dom

Suppose there's an element with the data attribute initially set:

```
<div id="mydiv" data-foo="bar"></div>
```

When I use jQuery to change the value of this data-key (`$('#mydiv').data('foo','baz')`) page's HTML remains unchanged yet `$('#mydiv').data('foo')` returns the new value correctly. Is it supposed to be so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value you see in source `html` is not the exact value of `DOM` but the intial value being assign and it is normal behaviour. The data changes the value in `DOM` but not the source `html`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is supposed to work that way.  If you want to change the actual attribute on the HTML, then you use `.setAttribute()` or jQuery's `.attr()`.

The main point of `.data()` is to provide an interface that works like properties on a DOM object, but does not have some of the problems that actual properties might have.  So, `.data()` gets its initial value from an attribute on the DOM object (if there was a matching attribute) and after that, all operations are separate from the actual DOM object.  The storage of a new value is in pure javascript, not a property on the DOM object.

Steps for `.data()` would look something like this:

```
var x = $(elem).data("test");
```

1. Get unique identifier for elem DOM object (a property on the DOM object).
2. If there is no unique identifier, create one and put it on the DOM object for future reference.
3. Check jQuery storage to see if there's a storage object for that identifier.
4. If there is not a storage object, then check the object for an attribute named `"data-test"` and returns it's normalized value (if present).
5. If there is a storage object, then see if a `"test"` property exists and return it's normalized value.

`.data()` also normalizes values into a javascript type so that `"true"` or `"false"` or numbers which would all be stored as strings when they are attributes on the object become booleans or actual numbers when you read them with `.data()`, thus simplifying your use of them.

Comment: You are probably editing my answer instead of yours, although I am quite happy with that :)

Comment: @Adil - Oops, yep it looks like maybe I helped you get the accepted answer.

Comment: Yes I do expect help from you, I guess you helped/guided me on serveral occasions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this its working-

```
 alert($('#mydiv').data('foo'));
   $('#mydiv').attr('data-foo','some');
```

But in alert its still showing BAR

Answer (score 0):

This will work like this only.
If you want to change the content of div so you can do like this,

```
$('#mydiv').html('baz');
```